# React Navigation 5: toggleDrawer() doesnt work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am working on React Navigation version 5. I am trying to show my drawer on the left through my `MealsNavigator.js` file.

Here's the code:

```
const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
                }}

            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

If we will zoom on the code where it happens:

```
 <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
                }}

            />
```

This shows the hamburger menu but when I try to click on it, it returns `ReferenceError: Can't find varible props`. I tried to remove the props but still it did not work.

Anyone knows what am I doing here wrong?

UPDATE: Here's the complete code on my `MealsNavigator.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import FiltersScreen from '../screens/FiltersScreen';

import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CATEGORIES, MEALS } from '../data/dummy-data';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => 
                                 navigation.toggleDrawer()}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
          })}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
        : createBottomTabNavigator();

const getNavigationOptions = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // Props for the ios navigator
        return {
            labeled: false,
            initialRouteName: 'Meals',
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            },
        };
    }
    // Props for android
    return {
        initialRouteName: 'Favorites',
        activeColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveColor: 'black',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor },
        shifting: true
    };
};

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()} >
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesNav}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator();

const FavoritesNav = () => {
    return (
        <FavoritesStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}>
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="Favorites"
                component={FavoritesScreen}
            />
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const mealId = route.params.mealId;
                    const selectedMeal = MEALS.find((meal) => meal.id === mealId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedMeal.title,
                    };
                }}
            />
        </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
    );
};



const FilterNav = createStackNavigator();

const FiltersNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <FilterNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <FilterNav.Screen
                name="Filters"
                component={FiltersScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Filters'
                }}

            />
        </FilterNav.Navigator>
    );
};


const mainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
    return (
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsFavTabNavigator} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
    );
  };


export default MealsTabNav;
```

Comment: you miss the props in `headerLeft`, just like `headerLeft: (props) => (your component using props.navigation)`

Comment: Props did not work on this.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple the navigator not have params is props that reason show errors:
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable props". If you remove props it still not work because you don't have navigation params.
To resolve that problem. You can use params navigation in options like this

```
 <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => 
                                 navigation.toggleDrawer()}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
          })}
            />
```

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import FiltersScreen from '../screens/FiltersScreen';

import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CATEGORIES, MEALS } from '../data/dummy-data';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => 
                                 navigation.toggleDrawer()}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
          })}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
        : createBottomTabNavigator();

const getNavigationOptions = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // Props for the ios navigator
        return {
            labeled: false,
            initialRouteName: 'Meals',
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            },
        };
    }
    // Props for android
    return {
        initialRouteName: 'Favorites',
        activeColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveColor: 'black',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor },
        shifting: true
    };
};

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (

            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()} >
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesNav}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator();

const FavoritesNav = () => {
    return (
        <FavoritesStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}>
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="Favorites"
                component={FavoritesScreen}
            />
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const mealId = route.params.mealId;
                    const selectedMeal = MEALS.find((meal) => meal.id === mealId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedMeal.title,
                    };
                }}
            />
        </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
    );
};



const FilterNav = createStackNavigator();

const FiltersNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <FilterNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <FilterNav.Screen
                name="Filters"
                component={FiltersScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Filters'
                }}

            />
        </FilterNav.Navigator>
    );
};


const mainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
    return (
      // Switch container to here<========================
      <NavigationContainer>
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsTabNav} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };

// Export drawer here <==================
export default MainNavigatorDrawer;
```

Comment: You can directly do navigation.toggleDrawer() no need to go through dispatch :)

Comment: Ok I tried this solution but did not work. I got `TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function(IN'navigation.toggleDrawer(); 'navigation.toggleDrawer' is undefined()`

Comment: Are you using drawer?

Comment: Yes `import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';` Let me post all codes.

Comment: Could you show me your code using createDrawerNavigator?

Comment: Yes, Thank for you updated. In your case you just export and using MealsTabNav about MainNavigatorDrawer you don't use it anywhere right?

Comment: How can we open drawer if we don't use it?

Comment: What do you mean can you update your answer on what you mean?

Comment: Sorry if my comment not enough for you. I edited my answer with your code. Pls check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218873/discussion-between-jones-smith-and-anh-devit).

Comment: Thank you @AnhDevit for your effort and time even though we did not solve this issue.

Comment: Anyone out there who can help figure it out?